'SignInsRequestBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Filter' and no accessible extension method
I am using Graph client to get details and here is the code
   var signIns = await graphClient
   .AuditLogs
   .SignIns
   .Filter($"UserPrincipalName eq '{UserPrincipalName}' and IsInteractive eq true and status/errorCode eq 0").OrderBy("CreatedDateTime")
   .GetAsync();

Packages Used:
Microsoft.Graph 5.56 version
I am getting below error

'SignInsRequestBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Filter' and no accessible extension method 'Filter' accepting a first argument of type 'SignInsRequestBuilder' could be found

I have tried many different Microsoft.Graph versions but unable to resolve it?

Try var result = await graphClient.AuditLogs.SignIns.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) => {  requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = "UserPrincipalName eq 'rukuser@XXX.onmicrosoft.com' and isInteractive eq true and status/errorCode eq 0";  requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Orderby = new string []{ "createdDateTime" }; }); 

Worked like charm. Could you explain more on what was the root cause? Also now line  var signInsD = signIns.Distinct();  is throwing CS1061 'SignInCollectionResponse' does not contain a definition for 'Distinct' and no accessible extension method 'Distinct' accepting a first argument of type 'SignInCollectionResponse' could be found

If you are making use of latest version then you need to make use of the code I pasted. The code you were using do not work for latest versions

To fetch the SignInLogs, modify the code like below:
Code snippet work for the latest version. Current version is 5.x
namespace GraphApiExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            var clientId = "ClientID";
            var tenantId = "TenantID";
            var clientSecret = "Secret";
            var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential);

            var userPrincipalName = "rukuser@XXX.onmicrosoft.com";

            // Query sign-in logs with filtering and ordering
            var result = await graphClient.AuditLogs.SignIns.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
            {
                requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = $"UserPrincipalName eq '{userPrincipalName}' and isInteractive eq true and status/errorCode eq 0";
                requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Orderby = new string[] { "createdDateTime" };
            });

            if (result?.Value != null)
            {
                foreach (var signIn in result.Value)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Sign-in ID: {signIn.Id}, UPN: {signIn.UserPrincipalName}, Date: {signIn.CreatedDateTime}");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No sign-ins found.");
            }
        }
    }
}



Seems like migration issue? ,  basically I am trying to add users User userToAdd = await graphClient.Users[UserPrincipalName].GetAsync();
await graphClient.Groups[GroupId].Members.(userToAdd); -  and this throws "CS1001 Identifier expected"  error.

@kudlatiger Post a new question with all the details and I will help you there

Done https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78900775/identifier-expected-error-while-adding-members-to-aad-using-graph-api

Sure will check

the result object do have method "Distinct()"!  The line    var signInsD = signIns.Distinct();  fails.
